# Conditonally joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table A with `id, isValid, name, x, y` columns and table B with `id, Aid1, Aid2, isValid, name` columns.

- Table A `id` is the primary key.
- Table B `id` is the primary key.
- Table B `Aid1` and `Aid2` are foreign keys both referencing table A `id`.

I want to select all rows from B and join it with A where:

- (`B.isValid = true`) AND
- (`A[B.Aid1].x` is between X1 and X2 AND `A[B.Aid1].y` is between Y1 and Y2) OR
- (`A[B.Aid2].x` is between X1 and X2 AND `A[B.Aid2].y` is between Y1 and Y2)

I've been messing around and googling and just can't get it to work. Is it even possible to do this with one query?

What I have so far and where I am stuck

```
SELECT B.id, B.Aid1, B.Aid2, A.name, A.x, A.y 
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A 
ON B.Aid1 = B.id OR A.Aid2 = B.id;
```

Comment: What are `X1, X2, Y1, Y2`? Are these user inputs?

Comment: Please add sample table contents and the desired results.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to do this as two queries, one for `Aid1` the other for `Aid2`. Then combine them with `UNION`. MySQL doesn't optimize `OR` conditions well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return a row from the B table if either of the related A records has coordinates that fall between the specified range.

In the example below, we are assuming the requirement is 10 < X < 20 and 5 < Y < 15

```
SELECT * FROM B
JOIN A 
ON B.Aid1 = A.id or B.Aid2 = A.id
WHERE A.x > 10 AND A.x < 20 AND A.y > 5 AND A.y < 15
```

You could end up with multiple rows for a singe record of B if both relationships with A returned meet the criteria. If that is a concern, you can use `GROUP BY` to limit the results to a single row per record.
[GROUP BY docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)